# List model --> orderbydescending System.DateTime does not work?

Tags: c#, linq, model

Sorry if this is a duplicate but I can't find a StackOverflow post that works for me.

I'm getting miffed over learning how to use list model w/ linq.  My problem here is sorting by DateTime had no effect.  I'm using .NET framework v4.5.  I'm using SQL DataReader to read data into list model, but instead of writing/posting sql object, I'm gonna manually specify the adding of data to list model manually for this posting.

```
public MyInventory : IDisposable
{
    public MyInventory {
        PurchaseId = -1;
        StockDate = null;
    }  
    public void Dispose() {
        //PurchaseId...
        StockDate = null;
    } 
    public long PurchaseId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StockDate { get; set; }
}

List<MyInventory> modelMyInventory = new List<MyInventory>();

modelMyInventory.Add(new MyInventory { PurchaseId = 2, StockDate = DateTime.Parse("01-02-2010") });
modelMyInventory.Add(new MyInventory { PurchaseId = 5, StockDate = DateTime.Parse("01-03-2011") });
modelMyInventory.Add(new MyInventory { PurchaseId = 7, StockDate = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2010") });

modelMyInventory.OrderByDescending(m => m.StockDate);
```

Thanks...

Comment: Is this a sql or a C# question? However, you should use the database to order your inventory.

Comment: I'm told this is a linq cuz of objects such as "OrderBy", "OrderByDescending", etc.

Comment: I can't use database query since it use table join.  Trying to keep it simple and keep class (or tables) seperate.

Comment: You can even order a query when you use joins ;-)

Comment: Join in list model is something I will have to study and learn from as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`OrderByDescending` method does not order in place, you need to re-assign again:

```
modelMyInventory = modelMyInventory.OrderByDescending(m => m.StockDate);
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see.  So that's what have to be done for it to work.  THanks man.  The example someone send to me didn't show that.  (Still have to wait a few minutes to click accepted answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
modelMyInventory.OrderByDescending(m => m.StockDate);
```

does not actually sort the `modelMyInventory` object. Instead, it returns a new enumerable that is sorted. So you should write:

```
modelMyInventory = modelMyInventory.OrderByDescending(m => m.StockDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
modelMyInventory.OrderByDescending(m => m.StockDate);
```

This does not *reorder* `modelMyInventory`.  This *returns* a new enumeration ordered by `StockDate`.

You can either create a new variable or store the new list in the same variable:

```
var modelSorted = modelMyInventory.OrderByDescending(m => m.StockDate);
```

or

```
modelMyInventory = modelMyInventory.OrderByDescending(m => m.StockDate).ToList();
```